# How can I make the program restart?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

There seems to be an error in restarting the program, it does not restart properly. It asks if you want to play again then asks for name of players tells you the goal then restarts by itself.

```
import random, time

#Variables
die1 = 0
die2 = 0
goal = 0


 tries1 = 0

tries2 = 0
sum = 0
sum2 = 0
choice = "y"

while choice == "y":
#Asking for the player's names
    player1 = input("What is your name, player1?")
    player2 = input("What is your name, player2?")

#The "goal"
    goal = random.randrange(5) + 1
    print("The goal is:", goal)

#First while loop for the first die rolled by the first player
    while die1 != goal:
        die1 = random.randrange(5) + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player1, "Your roll is:", die1)
        tries1 = tries1 + 1
        sum = sum + die1
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print("Your sum is:", sum)
#Second while loop for the second die rolled by the second player    
    while die2 != goal:
        die2 = random.randrange(5) + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player2, "Your roll is:", die2)
        tries2 = tries2 + 1
        sum2 = sum2 + die2
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print("Your sum is:", sum2)

        time.sleep(2)

#The statement at the end of the game
        print("\n\n""Player", "\t\t", "Goal", "\t\t", "# of Rolls","\t\t", "Sum of Rolls", "\n", player1, "\t\t", goal, "\t\t", tries1,"\t\t\t", sum, "\n", player2, "\t\t", goal, "\t\t", tries2, "\t\t\t", sum2)
        choice = input("Would you like to play again?: (y) or (n)")
        goal = 0
        tries1 = 0
        tries2 = 0
        sum = 0
        sum2 = 0
        break
```

Comment: assign all but `choice` variables inside the main loop and remove `break`. also make more relevant titles for your future questions.

Comment: I did and it didn't work so then I set all the variables back to 0 before break, but then the second player's loop does not work well meaning that the number does not keep regenerating numbers to reach the goal in the second loop

Comment: Please stop vandalising your own posts; they were bad enough to start with.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because at the end of the program you are breaking out of the main while loop no matter what. You should surround it with an if statement using the choice variable. Also The Last Statement is inline with the while for when the second player rolls therefore it will be executed in that loop. To fix that you going to need to reduce the indentation so it is executed at the end of the game. Also the tries1 variable is indented out a space so python will probably throw some form of syntax error at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. In place of your break statement, put:

   `if choice != 'y':
       break`

This will cause the outer while loop to go back to the beginning if the user has typed 'y'.  Otherwise you'll break out of the loop and the script will exit.

2. Move ALL the variable declarations from die1 through sum2 inside the while loop; otherwise they won't get initialized for the replay.

Comment: I just tried that but, the second player in the second loop does not regenerate numbers to reach the goal . @PaulCornelius

Comment: It should have worked.  Did you move die2 inside the loop?  If you didn't it wouldn't generate any new tries because die2 would already == goal.  I would initialize all the variables (except choice) at the very beginning of the loop, that way you don't initialize them twice.